# Elasticsearch: Alert on New IP Address

Tags: elasticsearch, ip, kibana, elastic-stack, filebeat

I've been stuck in a problem for 3 days now..I am trying to alert on new IP address but the format of log file is not helping me

[image]

so I've used a pipeline to parse the log with grok

```
%{NUMBER:bytes} %{IP:client} %{URIPATH:itstheip} %{GREEDYDATA:le-reste}
```

and then I've configured filebeat.yml :

```
output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["localhost:9200"]
  pipeline: my_pipeline_id`
```

but now I don't know what to do or where can I find the new parsed log file.

Comment: By default, the Filebeat logs are stored in indexes called `filebeat-yyyy.MM.dd` so you can probably find your data there with the new fields you've parsed. If that doesn't work, maybe show your full pipeline definition as well as a sample raw log line

Comment: @Val Thanks for the comment..I've finally found a solution..I had syntax errors in my  `filebeat.yml ` file and to detect them I've used the ` filebeat modules list ` command in Linux.

Comment: Cool, glad you figured it out